# wp_head() outputs in body

Tags: wp-head

I've got a simple header file which calls the wp_head method, however when i inspect the source the css links are made in the body and the `<head>` is empty.

My header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php get_template_part( 'components/navigation/navigation', 'main' ); ?>
```

My functions.php:

```
<?php 
function load_scripts() {
    echo ' test';
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your browser's attempt to avoid invalid markup. Your `echo ' test';` outputs something that does not belong in a `head` tag, so the browser closes it and opens the `body` tag. If you look at the actual unprocessed response from the server, it won't appear this way, but that `echo` shouldn't be there regardless, and this issue will disappear when you remove it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, however, after removing the echo statement it still comes out in the body.

Comment: Then you have something else outputting something other than a valid tag in your `head`.

Comment: This legit helped me track down the issue I was also having.  Thx!

Comment: I was using an echo statement to display debug info on the screen BEFORE I was outputting the meta tag and it was showing up in the body. Once I removed my debug output, the meta properly showed up in head section!